# blinking WS2812 fastLED with milis arduino

Tags: arduino, led, fastled

I'm trying to get my led to blink every 2 seconds using millis.
Delay is not a possibility as I have other sensors running.

So far I got this, but it does not seem to work

```
#include "FastLED.h"
#define NUM_LEDS 12 // number of LEDS in neopixel ring
#define DATA_PIN 10 // for neopixel ring
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

long period = 2000;        
long currentMillis = 0;
long startMillis = 0;

void setup() {
FastLED.addLeds<WS2812, DATA_PIN, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
}

void loop() {

 currentMillis = millis();

  if (currentMillis - startMillis >= period) {
    startMillis = currentMillis;
    leds[7]=CRGB(255,0,0);
    FastLED.show();

  }

}
```

Comment: The code as posted does not compile.  You're missing a setup and loop functions.  It is impossible to tell why your code doesn't work by only seeing the one snippet of it that was done right.  If you want help post an example that actually compiles and exhibits the problem.    Are those variable declarations really located right before the if statement?  If so then I wouldn't expect this to work as startMillis keeps getting set back to 0 every time the function gets called.  If that's not the problem then hopefully it at least illustrates why you need to post your code.

Comment: I figured the setup and loop would be implied

Comment: It seems to me that your time variables should be unsigned. I can post an answer explaining why if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Can you now explain what you mean by "not working".  The light doesn't light?  The delay time is wrong?  It doesn't upload?  Just saying "it doesn't work" is the single most useless thing you can say here.  If you want someone to be able to help you then you have to tell them what is wrong.

Comment: @jstarr that would be great, thanks!

Comment: Put you a line in the if statement that prints to serial to see if it is being called at the right rate.

Comment: Implied.  Some of us might say it's implied that you can read the documents and know how to post a quality question.  Vote to close due to lack of research and debugging detail.

Comment: @jstarr   I would expect this to run for a few weeks before that bug became an issue.  You should be fine up to 2^31 seconds before your timing variables go negative.

Comment: I'll also note that we still can't see it all.  I wonder what value NUM_LEDS has.  I can see a pretty big issue if that's not larger than 7.   We also can't see what's included.  I'll assume that it's just FastLED, but smart people don't ask the people they need help from to guess what they have.

Comment: OK.  SO I don't have a strip to test with, but I would expect this code to turn on the 8th led to red and leave it there and do nothing else ever.  Is that what's happening?   The title says something about blinking but I don't see any line anywhere that turns that led back off.  It just gets turned on red again and again every 2 seconds.  But it won't blink unless you turn it off sometimes too.

Comment: @Delta_G lol, good point.

Comment: Yes, @Delta_G you are right. It turns on, but does not turn off. Where in my code should I turn it of? In the if statement?

Answer (score 1):

Does this get you a little closer?

```
#include "FastLED.h"
#define NUM_LEDS 12 // number of LEDS in neopixel ring
#define DATA_PIN 10 // for neopixel ring
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

unsigned long period = 2000;        
unsigned long currentMillis = 0;
unsigned long startMillis = 0;
boolean ledOn = false;

void setup() {
FastLED.addLeds<WS2812, DATA_PIN, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
}

void loop() {

 currentMillis = millis();

  if (currentMillis - startMillis >= period) {
    startMillis = currentMillis;
    ledOn = !ledOn;
    if(ledOn){
      leds[7]=CRGB(255,0,0);
    }
    else {
      leds[7]=CRGB(0,0,0);
    }
    FastLED.show();
  }

}
```

Comment: It does not work. Only lighting up fast and shuts of

Comment: That sounds like power.  The code should blink it.  More details you've left out.  See how those missing details that you want us to "imply" just end up slowing everything down?

Comment: No no, sorry. The led lights up and stops. Not the arduino it self.

Comment: So the led comes on, two seconds later goes off, and never comes back on?  Are you sure you have the code copied right?  Sure you didn't get a brace out of place?